# How many CSS Files should there be for one website?

Tags: website-design, css

Well, the title is my question. I (the programmer) want exactly one for caching and compressing reasons but my designer keeps sending me separate files for each site.

Maybe there's a designer point of view to mention that I don't get yet.

Comment: Implementation questions for designers are best asked on doctype.com.

Comment: why is this offtopic? if you have a ton of stylesheets and are using them improperly, that will slow load times, which decreases ux, usability, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could let the designer produce as many as they like and then [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) them along with any JavaScript files to meet your caching and compression requirements. See the following for further information:

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

Multiple CSS files are easier to manage. You could just merge them into 1, and maybe even minimize them. A simple mechanism to merge multiple CSS-files:

```
COPY /Y sheet1.css+sheet2.css+sheet3.css combined.css
```